# iPython query keys/shape/size in dictionary (whos for a dictionary)

Tags: numpy, dictionary, ipython

I am a new user of iPython. I frequently handle large datasets, loaded from (for example) netcdf files. I load the data into dictionaries and would like to be able to interactively query what keys are associated with the dictionary, their shape, datatypes, and how much size they occupy in memory.

e.g., I have a dict called "dat", which has a number of keys associated with it:

```
In [21]: dat.keys()
Out[21]: 
['Yp1',
 'diag_levels',
 'PHIHYD',
 'iter',
 'UVEL',
 'VVEL',
 'T',
 'THETA',
 'Y',
 'X',
 'Xp1',
 'WVEL',
 'RHOAnoma']
```

I know I could then query each key to get their shape using Numpy's

```
np.shape(dat['Yp1'])
```

But I'm wondering if there's a function that will just return it all nicely formatted in one go, something like "whos", but that will actually query the dictionary.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be a list comprehension (normal Python)

```
[dat[x].shape for x in dat]
```

I don't have a `netcdf` (`h5yp`?) dictionary to test this one, so there may be an error.  But I think it's a straight forward dictionary/value problem.

A dictionary comprehension:

```
{x: dat[x].shape for x in dat}
```

will give a nice dictionary pairing of names and shape.

Other attributes could be added via a list.  They could even be formatted.

```
{k: [v.shape, v.dtype, v.size] for k,v in dat.items()}

{k: '%s: %s elems, %r'%(v.shape,v.size,v.dtype) for k,v in dd.items()}
```

For a fancier display you could look at the `whos` code, and pull out the relevant pieces to make your own magic

```
whos??
```

---

```
def whosdict( x, header='' ): 
    # a formatted display modeled on common object __str__ methods
    lines = [header]
    for k,v in x.items():
       aline = '%s\t\t%s: %s elems, %r'%(k, v.shape,v.size,v.dtype)
       lines.append(aline)
    astr = '\n'.join(lines)
    # could print instead of return string
    return astr
```

which could be used as

```
In [342]: print(whosdict(dd, 'dd dictionary'))
dd dictionary
x       (4,): 4 elems, dtype('int32')
y       (3, 4): 12 elems, dtype('float64')
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great, and a good part of what I want. Is there a way to add the datatype and size (bytes) of the keys also? (and yes, the netcdf reference isn't relevant) (edit: I tried {x: dat[x].dtype: dat[x].shape for x in dat} but the second colon is problematic)

Comment: Thank you thank you... this is just what I was after.

Comment: Ok - one more thing, this is excellent, and I'd like to write it into a function. I have something like this:                                                          def whosdict( x ):
    str =  {k: '%s: %s elems, %r'%(v.shape,v.size,v.dtype) for k,v in x.items()}
    print(str)  
    return;                                                                                                              But the print statement removes the newlines - how can I preserve them in the output? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot from your examples, and this completely solved my problem.